# List posts by their custom taxonomy term, with a condition

Tags: terms, categories, php

I have two custom taxonomies called "custom-category" and "file_type". I am using the below code to list all the terms of "file_type" along with their associated posts. Like so:

File_Type Term 1

- post
- post
- post

File_Type Term 2

- post
- post
- post

and so on...

My problem is that I need to add another condition to this. I want to only show the posts if they **also** have a specific term in "custom-category" taxonomy. So, for each file_type term, I want it to only show posts that have that term AND have the term "learning-units" in the custom-category taxonomy (term ID is 9).

I'm so confused. Here is my working code for listing posts by file_type term. How do I add that extra condition?

```
<?php

    $categories = get_terms('file_type');

    foreach ( $categories as $category ) :

    ?>

    <h2><?php echo $category->name; ?></h2>

    <?php

        $posts = get_posts(array(
          'post_type' => 'product',
          'taxonomy' => $category->taxonomy,
          'term'  => $category->slug
          ));

// Here's the second, nested foreach loop that cycles through the posts associated with this category

        foreach($posts as $post) :
          setup_postdata($post); 
        ?>


           <div class="product">

           <h3><span><?php the_title(); ?></span></h3>
           <?php the_post_thumbnail('product'); ?>
           <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="button">Learn More</a>


          </div>


        <?php endforeach; ?>


 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly add `'taxonomy_name'=>'term_slug'` in your current code.

```
 $posts = get_posts(array(
          'post_type' => 'product',
          'file_type'=> $category->slug,
          'custom-category' => 'learning-units'
          ));
```

For more reference check [WP_Query Taxonomy Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)

Comment: Facepalm! I had tried some variations of that in a previous iteration, which didn't work for other reasons. I forgot to come back to that once I got the main loop working. THANK YOU. This worked exactly as needed.

Comment: Note that that type of taxonomy argument was deprecated as of Version 3.1 in favor of 'tax_query'.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks for that info @Milo. I assumed this way was newer because it was less code. But I will try your solution below as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `tax_query` to set multiple taxonomy arguments. See [`WP_Query` Taxonomy Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) for more info.

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => $category->taxonomy,
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $category->slug
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'custom-category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => 9
        )
));
```